# Design of atomic bomb

Tags: design

Please see the following photo. (I cannot post it)
http://i1163.photobucket.com/albums/q554/startanewww/CIMG4548.jpg

Why is atomic bomb in a "fish-like" shape? (I don't know how to describe it) Is it specially designed for some purposes?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The picture you link to appears to be unusual for a air-droped bomb *only* in being particularly thick. I mean, it has the cylindrically symmetric casing of the weapon and some fins, just like every other iron bomb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The diagram looks like the [Fat Man bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Man) that was dropped on Nagasaki. The Wikipedia article gives lots of info on the design if you're intereted in pursuing it further.

The casing is just to make it aerodynamically stable so it fell in a controlled way. The bomb itself is spherical so the case could be spherical as well if it weren't for aerodynamic requirements.

Comment: It should be noted that the bomb dropped on Hiroshima was "Little Boy", using a different technology which was essentially a gun, shooting a "bullet" of uranium into a hollow "target" of uranium.  This design was naturally cylindrical, whereas Fat Man was naturally spherical.